# how to create a trigger to count all elements asociated to camp

Tags: mysql, sql

well let me explain I have 2 tables
city

```
city_id      name         
1            city1        
2            city2 
3            city3
4            city4
5            city5
```

pharmacy

```
   pharm_id      name      fk_city_id
       1          pharm1        1
       2          pharm2        2
       3          pharm3        3
       4          pharm4        3
       5          pharm5        4
```

I need a trigger to add a computed column in city that gives the amount of pharmacies asociated to that city
recently I did a view of this:

```
create view pharm_amount as (SELECT city.name, COUNT(*) FROM city INNER JOIN pharmacy ON city.city_id = pharmacy.fk_city_id GROUP BY city.name)
```

and I got this

```
 name       quantity
   city1         1
   city2         1
   city3         2
   city4         1
```

now I need a trigger to have a computed column in city table to look like this

```
city_id      name      quantity       
1            city1        1
2            city2        1
3            city3        2
4            city4        1
```

my trigger try:

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER `trigger1`
 BEFORE INSERT ON `pharmacy` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SELECT city.name, COUNT(*) FROM city INNER JOIN pharmacy ON city.city_id = pharmacy.fk_city_id GROUP BY city.name
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Error Code: 1415
Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `select` when you want to `update` your table.

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER `trigger1`
 BEFORE INSERT ON `pharmacy` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  # Here's your problem:
  SELECT city.name, COUNT(*) FROM city INNER JOIN pharmacy ON city.city_id = pharmacy.fk_city_id GROUP BY city.name
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Instead of `SELECT ...`, you need a query to update your table.

Something like `update city set quantity = (select count(1) from pharmacy where pharmacy.fk_city_id = city.city_id)` should work.

Comment: Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'quantity' in 'field list' when I try to     ``insert into pharmacy (name,fk_city_id) values ('pharm5', 5) ``

Comment: Run this `alter table city add column quantity int`, then add the trigger.

Comment: @AndresPasquel would you like to mark this answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

First you need a column for the quantitidy in your city table

```
ALTER TABLE city add column quantity integer DEFAULT NULL;
```

This trigger gets the count and insert s it into the new row.

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER `trigger1`
 BEFORE INSERT ON `pharmacy` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   SET NEW.quantity  = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM city c INNER JOIN pharmacy p ON c.city_id = p.fk_city_id WHERE c.name = NEW.name GROUP BY city.name);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

EDIT you should also have a AFTER INSER TRIGGER on pharmacy, so when a new pharmacy comes it could upodate the city table

EDIT2

You can also have a function for that

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `func_get_nopahr`(city_name  TEXT) RETURNS int
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
SET @city = city_name;
RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM city c INNER JOIN pharmacy p ON c.city_id = p.fk_city_id WHERE c.name = @city GROUP BY c.name);
END
```

And you can call it so

```
SELECT func_get_nopahr('ac');
```

Comment: so its always necessary to add a column with the trigger?, I was confused I think that the trigger will automatically add the calculated column, thank you for your help.